# How to retrieve the password from a java.sql.Connection object

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm looking for a way to get the password from a java.sql.Connection object.  I know there's a getUserName() method in the DatabaseMetaData object, but unfortunately no corresponding getPassword() method.  Using the debugger in Netbeans I can see a field for the password, so there must be a way to get this information using reflection, but thus far I've been unable to figure out how.

Comment: This will be interesting. I don't think that's possible through the public API, as you well pointed out. Perhaps somewhere in the Driver implementation or the DriverManager, if it is open source, you can find out. I doubt it is in the connection.

Comment: This is one of the most bizarre requirements I ever seen. Besides, it has a potential for security breach.

Comment: so, if you've seen the field in the debugger, why can't you get it using reflection?

Comment: java.sql.Connection is an interface, and does not have a "field for the password", or any other (non static) fields.

Comment: While the debugger shows me it exists, and the general hierarchy, I haven't been able to translate that into workable code to retrieve the password.  This is the first time I've had to dig into reflection, so my own inexperience is probably why I'm having difficulty.

Comment: are you looking for a "good" solution, or something you can whack together with reflection.  if the former, i don't think there is one.  if the latter, then you should probably show a bit of what you are seeing, and maybe someone can help you.

Comment: @Gillman I think we all should have started with this question: why in the world you do not know the password of the connections that you are using?

Comment: @edalorzo: Good question.  Actually, I do know the password, but here's the twist.  I have a Quartz scheduler running in Tomcat.  I want to use Quartz to run a command-line tool that requires the database username/password.  I was going to get the credentials from the Tomcat context file, but that was getting a little messy. So I figured I'd see what it would take to get them directly from the existing connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, the only way must be looking into the code. For instance, for MySQL using the latest driver (5.1.15). You can get the password like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  ConnectionImpl con = (ConnectionImpl) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3908/mydb?user=edalorzo&password=mandrake");

   System.out.println(con.getProperties().get("password"));

   con.close();
}
```

But for this, you would need to know the class hierarchy and its implementation details.

Other databases most probably will be different. If your database is open source, like MySQL you can know the details of the inner construction and find ways to retrieve the password.

Comment: This works very well and is much better than the reflection path I was heading down.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to the implementer of the JDBC to provide that since the user and password are being passed in as a Map to the [Driver](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html#connect%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Properties%29).

One way to know what the Password is, is to extend the driver and include that.

```
class CustomDriver extends ImplementerDriver {
  @Override
  public Connection connect(String url, Properties info) throws SQLException {
    super.connect(url, info);
    // Extract password from info.
  }

  public String getPassword() {

   ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the sever XML configuration file for the Connection Pool parameters, and get the password from there. sophisticated solution but it works.